# Oracle regular expression to exclude values with a pattern

Tags: regex, oracle

I need a regular expression to exclude values of a particular pattern.

```
REGEXP_LIKE( name,'[0-9].rm')  # this returns values like 123rm, 456rm etc.
```

I need to exclude values with the above format.

I tried both of the following, but it's not returning anything.

```
REGEXP_LIKE( name,'^[[0-9].rm]') 
REGEXP_LIKE( name,'^([0-9].rm)')
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: what values do you want to exclude? do you mean numbers? can you show the expected result by example?

Comment: i want exactly the negation of the above reg expression. it should return values like abc12, abc, ab12ac, rm123, rm12abc etc

Comment: doesn't `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(...)` work? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[0-9].rm', 'c');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the negation of your regexp, you should use `NOT` in the query condition:

```
select ...
  from ...
 where ...
   NOT REGEXP_LIKE( name,'[0-9].rm')
```